# Adding an existing app script to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to add an existing app script to a newly created googlesheet using app script? And automatically assigning it to a trigger?

For example I have a spreadsheet call spreedsheetA. Then my form will create spreedsheetB, is it possible to automatically add my app script to spreedsheetA to spreedsheetB with out copy + pasting it manually. All by using the appscript in my form.

Comment: For example, in your situation, how about copying "spreedsheetA" as "spreedsheetB"? About `Is it possible to add an existing app script to a newly created googlesheet using app script?`, you can achieve this using Google Apps Script API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects) About `And automatically assigning it to a trigger?`, for example, how about creating both the Spreadsheet and the container-bound script using a script?

Comment: I didn't think of that. Let me test that out. That's brilliant! Thank you kind sir!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that if copying "spreedsheetA" as "spreedsheetB" is the same goal you expect, that is the simpler solution than using Google Apps Script API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround to what @Tanaike proposed you can use the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive) to make the copy. Because bounded scripts are also copied when you perform a [`makeCopy()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname) operation.

Steps:

1. Create a new sheet and add a [bounded script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) via `Extensions > Apss Script`. Take note of the ID, in the example I will call it `SSA_ID`
2. Add your script. As probe of concept I just added this simple one:

```js
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp
  .getUi().alert('Hi from bounded script')
}
```

3. Create a [new](https://script.new/) script, and paste this code inside:

```js
function copySpreadSheet() {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(SSA_ID)
  const newFile = file.makeCopy(`SpreadSheetCopy_${new Date().toISOString()}`)
  Logger.log(newFile.getUrl())  
}
```

4. Run the script, grab the url and copy paste it in your browser. You will see that it contains a copy of the bounded script.

From there you can manipulate the copy and add it to an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), for example:

```js
ScriptApp.newTrigger('copySpreadSheet')
  .timeBased()
  .everyHours(6)
  .create();
```

---

###### Documentation:

- [`newTrigger(functionName)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))
- [`ClockTriggerBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)